# Detect from which side the mouse left a div

Tags: javascript, direction, mouseleave

I modified the code of the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15020514/1091014) of another question (which aimed to detect from which side the mouse ***entered*** a `div`) in order to make it detect from which side the mouse ***left*** a `div`.

[Here is the my code](https://jsfiddle.net/IanY/p7c482j7/). I changed the log to display in the console. But somehow the results are always being "right" or "bottom" and no "top" or "left".

Any advise, please?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine...

Comment: @Sagar Sorry. I mis-linked that best answer's jsFiddle. I had corrected the link to make it link to my jsFiddle.

Comment: Would the previous fiddle's mod work for you?

Comment: @Sagar Which one?

Comment: The one in jquery from where you have copied.

Comment: I think the problem is that it doesn't work with position: absolute. have you tried without that?

Comment: @Sagar That best answer works for me.

Comment: @IanY. this is interesting to note why javascript is not giving the same answer as jquery.

Comment: @JVLobo I deeply apologize for the comment. It seems positioning is affecting the answer. But why?

Comment: @IanY. I tested the absolute positioning effect for the best answer as well and the same bug seems to be happening.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been working a bit on the code and I've modified some stuff.

Since you're positioning your div with absolute position, you need to check the position on a different way.

First, I'm using `getBoundingClientRect()` which returns the position of the element (left, top, right and bottom).

Then I get the mouse coordinates and I calculate from which edge is closest.

You can see an example of my code here:

```js
document.querySelector('#content').onmouseleave = function(mouse) {
  var edge = closestEdge(mouse, this);
  console.log(edge);
}

function closestEdge(mouse, elem) {
  var elemBounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  var elementLeftEdge = elemBounding.left;
  var elementTopEdge = elemBounding.top;
  var elementRightEdge = elemBounding.right;
  var elementBottomEdge = elemBounding.bottom;

  var mouseX = mouse.pageX;
  var mouseY = mouse.pageY;

  var topEdgeDist = Math.abs(elementTopEdge - mouseY);
  var bottomEdgeDist = Math.abs(elementBottomEdge - mouseY);
  var leftEdgeDist = Math.abs(elementLeftEdge - mouseX);
  var rightEdgeDist = Math.abs(elementRightEdge - mouseX);

  var min = Math.min(topEdgeDist,bottomEdgeDist,leftEdgeDist,rightEdgeDist);

  switch (min) {
    case leftEdgeDist:
      return "left";
    case rightEdgeDist:
      return "right";
    case topEdgeDist:
      return "top";
    case bottomEdgeDist:
      return "bottom";
  }
}
```

```css
#content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

I hope that helps you.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15063296/1091014) of the other question noticed the issue of absolute positioning, too.